# How to set up a systemd service to listen on a socket and copy the contents to the clipboard?

Tags: ssh, systemd, services, clipboard, xclip

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/tmux-in-practice-copy-text-from-remote-session-using-ssh-remote-tunnel-and-systemd-service-dd3c51bca1fa) which will help me copy text from remote tmux sessions onto my local clipboard.

The first there is to setup a systemd service which listens on a given port on the local machine and copies the contents to the clipboard using xclip. I am unable to reproduce the results. The `xlclip.socket` file is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Network copy backend for tmux based on xclip

[Socket]
ListenStream=19988
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

The xclip@.service file is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Copy backend service piping input to xclip

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xclip -i -f -selection primary | /usr/bin/xclip -i -selection clipboard
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
```

The error that I get is: `Error: Can't open display: (null)`

This probably indicates that xclip cannot access the clipboard which is managed by XServer. How should I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.